# How i check if a dynamically loaded Angular Controller has been regestered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-controller

I have created an application that loads routes dynamically and in turn there controllers.

My controllers are added using an ng-repeat in my index file and then bootstrapped manually.

The issue i have is when i refresh, sometimes my routing loads and attempts to redirect to a given route before its controller is loaded.

My question is, is there a way to detect if a controller is loaded using some kind of event?

**Dynamically load my controllers:**

```
<script ng-repeat="script in clientScripts" ng-src="{{script}}"></script>
```

**Manually bootstrap the controllers**

```
app.config(function($provide, $compileProvider, $controllerProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider, uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider, $injector, toastrConfig, constant) {
        app.$$registerFactory = $provide.factory;
        app.$$registerService = $provide.service;
        app.$$registerCtrl = $controllerProvider.register;
        app.$$routeProviderRef = $routeProvider;
        app.$$httpProviderRef = $httpProvider;
        app.$$registerDirective = $compileProvider.directive;
...
...
```

**Initialize my controller**

```
app.$$registerCtrl('AchievementsController', AchievementsController);
```

**Dynamically load my routes**

```
/*
        // DYNAMIC CLIENT ROUTING
        // ======================
        // corresponding controllers and factories need
        // to be added in the client config.json
        */
        $rootScope.$watch('config', function(x, y, z) {
            if ($rootScope.config) {

                // get route json and start adding routes
                $http.get('../content/' + $rootScope.config.contentFolder + '/config/route.json').then(function(response) {
                    angular.forEach(response.data, function(value) {

                        // Add routes from client route.json
                        angular.module('dashboard').$$routeProviderRef.when(value.route, {
                            caseInsensitiveMatch: value.vars.caseInsensitiveMatch,
                            templateUrl: value.vars.templateUrl,
                            resolve: {
                                auth: function(AuthFactory) {
                                    return value.requiresAuthentication === true ? AuthFactory.IsAuthenticated() : AuthFactory.IsAnnonymous();
                                }
                            }
                        });




                    });

                    var route = SessionStorage.getObject('route');
                    if (route && $route.current.originalPath != route && route != '/dashboard') {
                        $location.path(route);

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```